# C-program using RS232 does only work when starting minicom

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I'm using a program for RS232 communication. The program works fine so far, but i need to start and quit minicom (and eventually switch off hardware flow control) before starting the program.

Below is the code I use to initialize the port. I already had a look at
http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html
and tried different further flags/options, such as explicitly set hardware flow control off, but it didn't help.

```
int open_port(void)
{
        int fd;
#ifdef DEBUG
printf("open port\n");
#endif
        fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
        if (fd == -1)
        {
                perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyS0");
        }
        else
        {
                if (port_set==0){
                        port_set=1;
                        struct termios options;
                        tcgetattr(fd, &options);
                        cfsetispeed(&options, B9600);
                        cfsetospeed(&options, B9600);
                        options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
                        tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);
                }
        }
        return (fd);
}
```

Comment: what about the code is not working? what is the specific problem?

Comment: Is port_set initialised somewhere may be a global?  No interest in return values or value of errno after function calls?  No wonder there's little info.  You can read/write stuff from serial lines even in stuff like perl scripts and use `stty < /dev/ttyS0` command to see and set the needed options, to get something working.  Have you turned off CANON and got it in raw mode?  What about IXON & IXOFF flags for flow control.. sure you need it to get something?  Used to just need it for large amounts of serial output or input if the host was unable to service the line for some reason.

Comment: Having to run **minicom** prior to your program implies that your program in not initializing the serial port.  Before and after you run **minicom**, use the shell command `stty -a -F /dev/ttyS0` to get all of the port's attributes.  The differences are apparently what you need to setup in your program.  BTW that `if (port_set==0)`conditional should not be in your program.  You ***unconditionally*** want to initialize the serial port after (successfully) opening it.

Answer (score 0):

For non-canonical mode, you need to use the macro cfmakeraw to simplify various settings required. Otherwise the program performs an blocking read until a terminating character like 0x0A is detected, which may never be sent. Insert this line

```
cfmakeraw(&options);// make raw
```

right after the line

```
tcgetattr(fd, &options);
```